# Executing python script on page load

Tags: javascript, python

How can I execute python script on page load using Javascript. I need to get some information that this script is getting but I can't use python directly in this html file.

Comment: Please share the research you've done already on the subject.  What web server/service is being used?  Apache, Nginx, Flask, Django, ... ?

Comment: Python doesn't run on the browser.

Comment: Client-side? You can't. You need to call your server, execute the script on it, and send the result back to the client.

Comment: I'm using nginx on ubuntu 18.04. I was trying to do whole thing in javascript but my understanding of this programming language is too bad to solve my problem in it. @S3DEV